# References about the symmetric products of a stack

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry

I would like to know references about a construction of the symmetric product (or the moduli space of effective divisors) $X^{(d)}$ of a stack $X$.

I am currently thinking about the following case: $X$ is a proper complex Deligne-Mumford stack. This means that the stack $X$ can be represented as a proper complex étale groupoid $Z_1 \rightrightarrows Z_0$ of complex dimension $1$.

Because I think that the construction of the symmetric spaces of a stack might be elementary for algebraic geometers, I am looking for a construction of the symmetric spaces of the stack $X$. But I have not found any references yet.

Similar settings are welcome.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! I see that [you are already on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/users/5206/jpmaths). I just wanted to remark that many of the top users from MO also frequent this site, and I hope that one of them will be able to respond to your question; but, if you are unable to get an answer here, I am sure that your question is also appropriate for MO.

Comment: Thank you for leaving a comment. I think that I should define the symmetric product by myself.